# Ember: Reuse nested route in different parents

Tags: ember.js

I wanted to know how to reuse a nested route in different parent route.
For example:

Template routeA:
    {{outlet}}  -> routeX

Template routeB:
    {{outlet}} -> routeX

```html
Router.map(function() {

  this.route('routeA', function(){
    this.route('routeX', {resetNamespace:true});
  });

  this.route('routeB', function(){
    this.route('routeX', {resetNamespace:true});
  });

})
```

I need to use {{link-to 'routeX'}} to show routeX inside the current parent.
In the example always shows the routeB when I use {{link-to 'routeX'}}

I have 2 aproax to solution:

1) Put 1 child route in routeA and other in routeB:

```html
Router.map(function() {

      this.route('routeA', function(){
        this.route('routeX');
      });

      this.route('routeB', function(){
        this.route('routeX');
      });

})
```

and use {{link-to 'routeA.routeX'}} and {{link-to 'routeB.routeX'}}
but in this aproax I have a duplicate code.

2)

```html
router.map(function() {
    this.route('*wildcard', function(){
       this.route('routeX', {resetNamespace:true});
    });
})
```

this option works but in the url appear "undefined"  http://...undefined/routeX

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Would it be likely for you to use  either a component or mixin, in both routeA.X and routeB.X to share functionality ? What don't you want to repeat in route X twice, that motivates your use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I recommend using either a component or mixin to share whatever code or functionality you need between those two similar routes.

That would look something like this

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  model() {
    return Ember.Object.create({title: 'Awesome'})
  }
});
```

and then use it in your route like so,

```
import ReUseMixin from '../../mixins/re-use'
export default Ember.Route.extend(ReUseMixin,{
```

or by defining your component, as lets say `re-use.hbs` and `re-use.js`

you can just use that in routeA/routeX and routeB/routeX as
`{{re-use}}`

Here is a [link](https://ember-twiddle.com/4acad468c0b0e18d67c1b148397e7fee?openFiles=templates.routeb.routex.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.re-use.hbs) to an ember twiddle, that demonstrates what I would recommend, hopefully that can provide you with a solution.